# Results for $y^{\prime\prime}(x) = a(x)y(x)$, where $a(x) > 0$.

Tags: reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm looking for references to any known results regarding solutions to the following 2nd order ODE $y''(x)=a(x)y(x)$, where $a(x)>0$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why you deliberately restrict $a(x)>0$ ?

Comment: http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode-toc2.htm is already quite a good reference, but you should choose the suitable ones by yourself.

Comment: @doraemonpaul.  One encounters such an equation when trying to prove an arc-sine law for diffusions.  I require $a(x) > 0$ mainly to ensure a certain stochastic differential equation has a unique solution.

Comment: What would you like to be true?

Answer (score 1):

The classic reference on ordinary differential equations is Kamke, Differentialgleichungen I and II (in German), which features an extensive list of known ODE's and their solutions, as well as an explanation of solving techniques.

For anything more specific, you have to be more specific. Where does this ODE come from? What else is known about a(x)?

Comment: As stated above:  "One encounters such an equation when trying to prove an arc-sine law for diffusions. I require a(x)>0 mainly to ensure a certain stochastic differential equation has a unique solution."  For the sake of generality, one would not want to make additional assumptions on $a$.

Comment: In that case, you cannot say very much except if both y(x0) and y'(x0) are positive (or both are negative), in which case y grows without bounds if a(x) is bounded away from zero (i.e. a(x) >= eps > 0). In the general case, everything can happen.